# How to make TabBar of react-native-tab-view smaller?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-tab-view

I am using `react-native-tab-view`, but the TabBar is big, I want to make it small. How to customize it ? Applying margin/padding 0 didn't work.
Applying small height worked but the text went missing.
How to make it small or more customizable ?

```
<TabView
 ...
                renderTabBar={props =>
                    <TabBar
                        {...props}
                        indicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
                        style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink' }}
                        tabStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'teal' }}
                        renderLabel={({ route, focused, color }) => (
                            <Text style={{ color, margin: 8 }}>
                                {route.title}
                            </Text>
                        )}

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `tabStyle` prop for `TabBar`. By default it [has](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/blob/master/src/TabBarItem.tsx#L254) a style:

```
minHeight: 48,
```

So in your case:

```
<TabView
 ...
  renderTabBar={props =>
      <TabBar
          {...props}
          indicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink' }}
          tabStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'teal', minHeight: 30 }} // here
          renderLabel={({ route, focused, color }) => (
              <Text style={{ color, margin: 8 }}>
                  {route.title}
              </Text>
          )}
    }
```